# Parameters of the 3 phase geared induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, vfd

I have a 3 phase geared induction motor. The name plate is below image.
I couldn't find any datasheet from internet.

Explain me parameters that on nameplate for entering to VFD.

I need to know Rated power.( This has a code. I cant understand that.)

What are n1,n2 means?

Why two value for cosφ and amperage?

This motor also able to run using delta configuration?

[image: Nameplate]

Comment: It has two running configurations so that explains the multiple values. You need to know which configuration you will use...

Comment: @SolarMike It has only Y configuration symbol. And also two voltages not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The / provides the nominal ratings at different operating conditions.

On the high end: 75% duty cycle, when the motor drives a 0.28kW load the rated current is 0.95A, spins at 2660 rpm, geared down to 176 rpm has a pf of 0.85.

Low end: 25% duty cycle, 0.071kW load at 0.75A, spins at 650 rpm, geared down to 43 rpm has a pf of 0.75.

The motor is connected internally as a wye (Y), but that has no bearing with how it is connected to the source.

The motor can be connected in delta (Δ) or wye.  In a Δ, the line currents will be less.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What did you mean duty cycle?

Comment: Depends how VFD works.  Corresponds to 25/75% data.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know Rated power.( This has a code. I cant understand that.)

The two power ratings, 0.07 kW and 0.28 kW are the ratings at the two motor speeds, 650 RPM and 2660 RPM. That would be consistent with two-speed operation with full torque available at each of the two speeds. I believe "S3-25/75% designates a duty cycle. If you search "S3 motor duty cycle" and "IEC" you may be able to find a full explanation.

IEC Duty Cycle S3

> The duty type S3 is defined as a sequence of identical duty cycles,
>   each including a time of operation at constant load and a time
>   de-energized and at rest. The contribution to the temperature-rise
>   given by the starting phase is negligible.

For the specific nameplate marking that would mean:

For the low speed, 25% of the duty cycle time at full load and 75% at rest

For the high speed, 75% of the duty cycle time at full load and 25% at rest.

The the acceptable load for continuous operation is not defined. However the statement about the contribution of starting to temperature rise implies that the motor can not operate continuously at full load.

The use of IEC duty cycle designation format on the nameplate implies that the IEC definition applies. Some national standard may apply, but the common national standards (except NEMA) seem to be close to the IEC standard.

> What are n1,n2 means?

n1 lists the motor speeds and n2 lists the corresponding speeds at the output of the gear.

> Why two value for cosφ and amperage?

The values correspond to operation at the two speeds and power ratings listed.

> This motor also able to run using delta configuration?

If is able to run using the delta connection, that should be marked on the nameplate.

This can probably be operated with a VFD using either winding, but determining a safe operating torque at any speed and duty cycle will be very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: It shows a Y/Y configuration, so that would be a 2 speed 2 winding motor, the connection diagram is likely on the inside of the wiring compartment. An S3 duty cycle means it is designed to be used in repeated on-off cycles with equal on and off times. It ALSO means it is NOT designed for continuous operation.

Comment: @JRaef Can't I use this motor with delta configuration ?
What is Y/Y configuration. Can you give me a link with described that?

Comment: I assumed that the acceptance of the answer by StainlessSteelRat settled the question. @JRaef pointed out a very important issue. I had assumed that the two speed markings were concerned with VFD use because there was no diagram or mention of the number of motor leads in the question. It makes perfect sense that Y/Y indicates a two-speed, 6-lead motor with two completely separate windings. If that is the case, power is connected to 3 leads for high speed and the other three for low speed. You can use not all 6 at one time and there is no way to make a delta connection. I revised my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The INTERNAL connections in the motor are wye (star), two separate windings for two separate speeds. There is no option for connecting in delta, this is a 380V motor only. So for selecting the 2 speeds, you need a 2 speed 2 winding (2S2W) motor starter, with separate Overloads and Short Circuit protection for each set of windings. Or just use one set of windings for one speed.